# Jquery not called?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

```
<div>
<asp:Button ID="btnCalculate" runat="server" Text="Calculate Claim" OnClientClick="cfrm();"/>
</div>
<div style="visibility: hidden;">
    <asp:Button ID="btnYes" runat="server" OnClick="btnYes_Clicked" />
</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function cfrm() {
                var fee = $('[id$=lblTotalProcedureFee]').text();
                if (fee > 500) {
                    if (confirm('Are you sure to do this operation?')) {
                    $('#<%= this.btnYes.ClientID %>').click();
                    }
                }
            }
</script>
```

I am trying to call "btnYes_Clicked" from the query. Refer to above code. It doesn't work.. then i edited the code just to test. First click, it doesn't work. 2nd click, it goes to the btnYes_Clicked event. I'm using master page which has update panels. Please help. Thanks..

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function cfrm() {
                    $('#<%= this.btnYes.ClientID %>').click();                     
            }
</script>
```

Comment: try `.trigger('click')`

Comment: Are your script code written below the `<div>`?

Comment: @pktangyue yes. it's written below div

Comment: try to put it above `<div>`

Comment: thanks to both of u.. i tried. but doesn't work ..

Comment: Are you putting in a fee of < 500?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this, using `return` in `OnClientClick` and in `cfrm` to prevent form unwanted form submitting :

```
<div>
<asp:Button ID="btnCalculate" runat="server" Text="Calculate Claim" OnClientClick="return(cfrm());"/>
</div>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function cfrm() {
                var fee = $('[id$=lblTotalProcedureFee]').text();
                if (fee > 500) {
                    if (confirm('Are you sure to do this operation?')) {
                    $('#<%= this.btnYes.ClientID %>').click();
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
</script>
```

Hope this will help